# Trying to understand vsftpd log

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

I'm currently learning Linux and using FTP however I can't make sense of the log file any help would be appreciated.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log# cat vsftpd.log
Mon Jan 18 06:39:48 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:40:12 2021 [pid 1] [ppolly] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:42:46 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:43:03 2021 [pid 1] [ppolly] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 06:43:13 2021 [pid 3] [ppolly] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "192.168.20.105", "/home/ppolly/list.txt", 284 bytes, 81.91Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 18 07:10:25 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.105"
Mon Jan 18 07:10:34 2021 [pid 1] [fred] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:12:35 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:12:57 2021 [pid 1] [admin] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:03 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:13 2021 [pid 1] [root] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:20 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:35 2021 [pid 1] [administrator] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:13:52 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:07 2021 [pid 1] [ftpadmin] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:16 2021 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:26 2021 [pid 1] [adminftp] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
Mon Jan 18 07:14:59 2021 [pid 1] [pete] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.20.120"
```

Comment: Hi. It might help if you can elaborate on what part of the log is confusing you. It seems fairly clear to me: different user accounts are trying to connect. Most are failing, but one succeeded.

Comment: Hi. Im trying to understand what [pid 1] [pid 2] mean sorry for being really vague.

Comment: Well, 'pid' stands for 'process ID'. Every running process in Linux has one. Although, pid 1 is usually reserved for the first process to run on a system after booting (i.e. `init`), so I doubt those are system PIDs. It might be a good idea to edit your question to clarify that is what you are confused about.